# Find Last Defined Element in Vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to get the last defined element in a C++ vector, but both vector::capacity and vector::size are just giving me the max size. For example:

```
int main() {
     char* array = new char[MAX_SIZE]; //MAX_SIZE is a const int equaling 100
     std::cout << "Enter in a number: ";
     std::cin >> array;
     std::vector<char> cVector;
     cVector.reserve(MAX_SIZE); 
     cVector.assign(array, array + MAX_SIZE);
     for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = cVector.begin(); i != cVector.end(); ++i) 
     {
          std::cout << *i;
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Size: " << cVector.size() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Actual size: " << cVector.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter in a number: 55
55
Size: 100
Actual size: 100 [Should say 2]
```

I've tried using vector::end() and similar methods, but there's no way for me to get the index of the last element.

Comment: the code does what it should do. What do you mean by last defined element? You construct `cVector` with the size `MAX_SIZE`. And why don't you just use `std::string`?

Comment: My apologies. I originally used a dynamic array and defined filled it there, but later changed to a normal array. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Why should the actual size say 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `reserve(MAX_SIZE)`, you change the capacity, so the output `100` is what it should be. That loop where you print out the values, actually iterates all 100 times, but all the remaining chars are `\0`, so `std::cout` interprets those pointers as empty strings. Here is a slightly modified version that create a proper vector, so `vector.back()` will point to the last element and `vector.end()` to the next position in memory.

```
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Enter in a number: ";
    std::cin >> s;
    std::vector<char> cVector;
    cVector.reserve(MAX_SIZE);
    cVector.assign(&s[0], &s[0]+s.size());
    for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = cVector.begin(); 
         i != cVector.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size: " << cVector.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Actual size: " << cVector.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Note that I used `std::string` only to make it more C++-ish. You can keep using `char[]`, just you need to replace your original assignment with:

```
cVector.assign(array, array + strlen(array));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! It's strange that filling the vector with a char array doesn't work but doing it with a string does.

Comment: @user3288091 sorry about this confusion. This will also work with `char[]`, see the update.

Answer (score 1):

`size()` gives the length of the vector (the number of elements actually in it, not the number of elements that it can currently fit). You're seeing the same number because you call `assign(array, array + MAX_SIZE)` on the vector, which will obviously fill it with `MAX_SIZE` elements.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to add in the contents of the array to the vector?

Comment: This whole code is just 5 lines if you use a `string` instead. If you insist on using an array, replace `MAX_SIZE` by the length of the "string" in the char array.

Comment: True, I guess that's the best case. Thank you for your help.